# Limitar Input con CSS

Tags: html, css

He echo un Input y le puesto como fondo un icono (€) con CSS. El caso es que al escribir se sobrescribe encima. Habría alguna forma de que tuviera un tope?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que quede asi y que pueda seguir escribiendo sin solapar el icono:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Agrega el código css y el html correspondiente a ese input así podemos ayudarte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes asignar un tamaño al padding derecho sabiendo que va a estar el icono, tendrás que calcular la distancia que quieres. Algo así:

```
input{
  padding-right: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Es exactamente lo que necesitaba, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

puedes usar Pseudoelementos para agregar el prefijo, usas un label para poder estilizar bien un input, y agregas una clase CSS por la moneda o prefijo que quieras.

Esto tambien se puede hacer por javascript

```css
.inputcss{
  border:1px solid grey;
}

.inputcss input{
  border:none;
  outline:none;
  background-color:transparent;
}

.usd::before{
  content:'$';
  margin-right:6px;
}

.eur::before{
  content:'€';
  margin-right:6px;
}
```

```html
<label class="inputcss usd"><input type="text" /></label>
<label class="inputcss eur"><input type="text" /></label>
```